# The word "theorem" of a theorem is not bold if it appears inside another environment

Tags: theorems, amsthm

I'm typing up solutions to a problem set. I've defined a `theorem` and `solution` environment, as in the following document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm} 
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
 The word ``theorem'' at the beginning of a theorem is bold, unless it appears inside a solution.
\end{theorem}

\begin{problem}
 What is $2+2$?
\end{problem}

\begin{solution}
 We use the following theorem.
\begin{theorem} Numbers can be added.\end{theorem} 
The result is therefore $2+2=4$.
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

For the theorem that is *outside* the solution, the word "Theorem" appears correctly as bold. However, *inside* the solution environment, the title for the theorem environment is italic, matching the style for the solution environment.

How do I get the theorem inside the solution to be correctly boldface?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shortcoming of `amsthm`. You can cure it by using `thmtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\itshape,
]{myplain}
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
]{mydefinition}
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\itshape,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
]{myremark}

\declaretheorem[
  style=myplain,
  name=Theorem,
]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[
  style=mydefinition,
  name=Problem,
]{problem}
\declaretheorem[
  style=myremark,
  unnumbered,
  name=Solution,
]{solution}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
 The word ``theorem'' at the beginning of a theorem is bold, unless it appears inside a solution.
\end{theorem}

\begin{problem}
 What is $2+2$?
\end{problem}

\begin{solution}
 We use the following theorem.
\begin{theorem} Numbers can be added.\end{theorem} 
\begin{problem} Numbers can be added.\end{problem} 
The result is therefore $2+2=4$.
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]